# Can't reach the Pokemon while catching (0.33.0)

Tags: pokemon-go

Since the last update, twice, a pokemon appear but when trying to catch it, is too far away.
I throw the ball as *far* and *fast* as I can, but never reach it..and have to run away from the pokemon.

I mean, I played a lot (I'm level 18) and I don't think it's me, that I'm a noob or something.

I tried with pokeball and superball, also throwing some berries.

So, Can I assume is something about the update? Anyone know why this happen?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: no v.v i didnt think about it at the moment :/ they were a pidgeot and a zubat.

Comment: @lois6b yep, same here. Had a Pidgeot with CP of ???, so I would like to have catched it. However, I missed roughly 8 balls, and only 2 hit the target. Too much swiping result in an undetected swipe and a miss, too less swiping results in a ball not far enough, so a miss.

Comment: i couldnt even hit the target. i spent too many balls and said: f*&$k it, and leave. it wasnt even that powerful

Comment: Don't touch the ball/display before you actually swipe and throw it like a finger snip. This way you can throw further. At least this works for me. Also I believe curve balls can be thrown further than normal throws.

Answer (score 2):

When you turn AR on and then off again, your Pokémon should be centered on your screen and well within the reach of your pokeballs.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me sometimes when I'm attempting to catch a Pokémon like Golbat, Muk, etc. They appear pretty far away and when you fail your first catch attempt they usually move even further.

The trick is to put your finger on the very bottom of the screen a swipe it all the way up (across the whole display) quickly. It will take a lot of practice but you should master it eventually. Also when you catch a Pokéball at the very bottom, sometimes it bugs out and even a slight move will throw the Pokéball very far which comes quite handy in situation like this.

Also it looks like this "issue" is platform dependend. I play on Android device and most of my friends own iPhones. After some experiments and swapping of phones we concluded that throwing a Pokéball to great distance is more difficult on my Android phone (or at least specifically on my device) than on their iPhones.